# How many children did Andrew Laeddis have?

Tags: character, shutter-island

I was reading some questions and also some answers about *Shutter Island* (like [this](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/18533/21342) one and [this](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/18530/21342) one) last night and most places it says Andrew Laeddis' wife murdered their 2 children.

When I saw the movie, there were 3 children.

1. Did I watch a different version of the movie?
2. Or were there 2 children in the book? I haven't read the book yet.
3. Or am I just hallucinating like Andrew himself?

Just to prove that the third question is false I have an image from the movie as strong evidence

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Three** children.

The two questions you quoted were both answered by me. Answering the question in the first link you posted, I quoted from the second link you posted. The original asker in that question had mentioned two children and I rather mistakenly continued from this mistake and answered referring to two children instead of three.

It is three children, as confirmed by both the film in the pictures above and [the novel](https://vk.com/doc14694589_298869584?hash=e97db0504267169648&dl=94c4c411a0adeab053):

> She drowned her three children in the
>   lake behind her house.

I've added asterisked amendments to both of my previous answers to indicate this mistake.

Comment: Even if it might make this question even more substanceless, it would probably be cleaner to simply change the 2 to 3 in your two referenced answers, rather than that elaborate construction with saying 2 and including a verbose footnote that it's actually 3.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson: I did the opposite. I said three, and put a footnote in saying it was originally two (otherwise this question becomes invalidated).

Comment: Hmm, granted...